# How to shift an option of the select tag to right?

Tags: html

I need to do something like this.

[image]

I've already tried to add `nbsp` symbols, but I am not sure it is the best thing I can do

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to achieve, `<optgroup>` may be applicable.

Comment: Adding your code to the question makes it more clear.

Comment: please share your tries/codebase

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this attribute to the option:

```
dir="rtl"
```

```html
<select>
   <option dir="rtl">RTL Text</option>
   <option>This is an example</option>
</select>
```

**Do the same using `optgroup`:**

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```